# click() in jQuery can it fire a server side button

Tags: jquery, asp.net, gridview

I've got an asp.net gridview.
Within it I have 2 ImageButtons like so:

```
<ItemTemplate>
 <asp:ImageButton class="DeleteLineItem" style="display:none;" ID="ibDelete" runat="server" CommandName="DeleteRow" ImageUrl="images/d.gif"
                                                        ToolTip="Delete Line Item?" />
  <asp:ImageButton class="TempDeleteLineItem" OnClientClick="return false;" runat="server" ToolTip="Delete Line Item?" ImageUrl="images/d.gif" />
                                            </ItemTemplate>
```

Notice the first one's visibility is set to false, the second one has a `OnClientClick="return false;"` as to avoid a post back...

My objective is to remove a row from the gridview with a fade effect, and then call the server side code behind the ibDelete (the first one whose visibility is set to false).

```
$(".TempDeleteLineItem").click(function() { 
    $(this).closest("tr").fadeOut(5000, function() { 
        alert('hi1');
        $(this).remove();
        alert('hi2');
        $(this).closest(".DeleteLineItem").trigger('click');
        alert('hi3');
    }); 
});
```

All the alert's display and the fade effect works and I am not getting a script error..but the click event isn't firing.
I must be using trigger() incorrectly?

## Edit

I have also tried

```
$(".TempDeleteLineItem").click(function() { 
    $(this).closest("tr").fadeOut(5000, function() { 
        alert('hi1');
        $(this).prev(".DeleteLineItem").bind('click');
        $(this).remove();
        alert('hi2'); 
    }); 
});
```

And I've tried `.trigger` and I've tried `.live` and all seem to be the same issue.
I get the fade working and the remove working but the click event doesn't seem to fire...

Answer (score 1):

When you set a server side control visibility to false then HTML for that control is not rendered and hence your jquery is not even finding the control and no trigger is happening (Check the view source of your page and you wont find the image button there).
Rather than setting Visible="false", you need to make the control to hide using CSS i.e set a css class on this button which has display:none. Then it will render in HTML and your jquery will trigger the event fine.

Comment: ok i will change that to display:none via css, and update you guys

Answer (score 1):

Your control ibDelete is `Visible="false"`, it will not be rendered on the client, so it cannot be triggered by JavaScript. A simple solution would be to hide it with CSS:

```css
.DeleteLineItem { display: none; }
```

Since your selector does not seems to work, it probably could be:

```js
$(this).closest ('tr').find ('.DeleteLineItem').trigger ('click');
```

Assuming the grid is rendered in a table, with no nested tables.

If it select the button but still not fire the postback, try copying the `onclick` generated in your function, something like:

```c#
WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions("some$naming$container$ibDelete", "", true, "", "", false, false));
```

That would manually provoke the post back.

Note that the *most correct* way to implement this would be to write your own WebControl that implements `IPostBackEventHandler`, and on the client calls `__doPostBack (...);` after the fadeout.

Comment: I changed it to display none but the click event is still not wokring

Comment: Hmm...maybe look at my answer?

Comment: Effectively the selector is not correct. Not sure if `prev` is the way to go, but that's probably the case.

Comment: @all i tried previous it still does not fire the click event.         `$(this).prev(".DeleteLineItem").trigger('click');`

Comment: To give et a try, you could check the genereted HTML for your `.DeleteLineItem` button, on copy/paste the `onclick` attribute in your function, e.g. repalce `$(this).prev (...).trigger ('click')` with the `__doPostBack` call.

Comment: @Johnny5 Im not sure what you mean, can you post it as an edit to your answer, its easier to read then on comments.

Comment: @Johnny5 looks like the selector is not picking up anything. I then tried 'WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions('gvLineItems$ctl02$ibDelete2', '', true, '', '', false, false))' inside my jquery with no results.

Comment: @Johnny5 if I do just this: '$(".DeleteLineItem").each (function () { alert ('hello!'); });' it alerts 3 times (the number of rows in my grid...so we know we have the right class name :) the issue is how to filter it to the one I am currently after...can i pass it clientid???

Comment: @Johnny5 let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2370/discussion-between-ojm86o-and-johnny5)

Comment: Ack spoke too soon...err sometimes this is working other times it isnt...i wonder if it is because all of this is wrapped in a Update Panel asp.net

Answer (score 1):

Your are looking for [prev()](http://api.jquery.com/prev/), like this: `$(this).prev('.DeleteLineItem').trigger('click')`

closest() = "Get the first ancestor element that matches the selector, beginning at the current element and progressing up through the DOM tree."

Also I have no idea what your asp will look like when it's generated, could be nice to tell me :) I'm on the PHP side...

Comment: i tried prev as well with no luck, the fade happens but the click event doesnt fire.

Comment: @bleckert - see my edit in my post, i've tried prev and then I've used .live and .bind but its the same result...

Answer (score 0):

try

```
.live('click',function(){/*.. function */})
```

and

```
.bind('click',function(){/*.. function */})
```

see if they provide better results

### edit

`live()` now being deprecated you should use `.delegate` instead. http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

and for newer versions of jQuery (1.7+) you should be using `.on()` http://api.jquery.com/on/

If you read the `.on()` notes you will see that `.live()` is not recommended for any versions anymore. There were some serious issues with it that have been outlined in many posts here et al.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you want to trigger the button click as that would make your page reload, which render the pretty fade as pointless. You need to add an ajax method to the server, either using WCF or via the MS AJAX tools. You then call that via jQuery's ajax method to have it do the delete on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason why you need to trigger the button from with JS/jQuery?  I may be missing a nuance here, but it seems like you could simply add OnClientClick="doFadeEffect(this)" to your ibDelete image button.  When they click it, doFadeEffect will get called and you'll get a chance to fade-out the row.  Then as long as doFadeEffect returns true, the postback will happen as normal.

Answer (score 0):

Try .live()

It should be used like below for latest version of Jquery : 1.9 and later

```
$('body').on('click', '.myButton', function)
```

follow this link for latest usage of the function.
[jQuery 1.9 .live() is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14354040/jquery-1-9-live-is-not-a-function)